# Setting Height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm checking if the cards- wrapper is having list-view class. If yes then i'm getting the current height of the mason div and when user clicks on the load-more button i'm adding 100px to the current height and setting that to the mason.

But issues is when i clickon the .load-more button setListHeight function is not calling

Please tell what i'm doing wrong ?

```js
if ($(".cards-wrapper").hasClass("list-view")) {
    $('.load-more').on('click',setListMoreHeight);
}

function setListMoreHeight(){
    alert('called');
    var currentHeight = $('.mason').height() + 100;
    console.log(currentHeight);

    $('.mason').height(currentHeight);
    console.log(currentHeight);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your if-statement is only getting evaluated *once*. If it's false, then the click event does not get bound, and the if statement *is never evaluated again*.

I would do something more like this:

```
$('.load-more').on('click', function() {
    if ($(".cards-wrapper").hasClass("list-view")) {
        setListMoreHeight();
    }
})

function setListMoreHeight(){
    alert('called');
    var currentHeight = $('.mason').height() + 100;
    console.log(currentHeight);

    $('.mason').height(currentHeight);
    console.log(currentHeight);

}
```

Now, rather than the click event being conditionally bound, the click event is *always* in effect. We only call the function if the condition is met.

Comment: yarp this makes more sense - removed my answer, though I would still argue the case for using $.fn alongside this

Comment: Creating a jQuery plugin/object method for something this trivial seems hardly necessary. Plus, the answer is more about logic and conditional evaluation than code preference. If you start adding *too* much to the answer, you've essentially re-written OP's code into something different. I find that re-using OP's code and correcting only what *has* to be corrected to be the clearest way for them to understand where they went wrong.

Comment: trivial as it may be, it can be now globally used throughout the project - unless the OP only intends to use the function in one place, in which case I agree, doing a object method is a tad overkill. And yeah, once I got what was asked it made sense :) and ah I was going for the, this how you use it, now use it haha rather than a "here's the direct answer" approach but no worries - this should be the accepted answer :)